# Trying to change the backgroundColor of a div depending on the background color that is being applied in the current div.

Tags: jquery, events, if-statement, background-color

Hi every one I'v been learning jquery for about 3 months now and I cant figure this out.

What I am trying to do is change the background of a div (.box) by a click. I know how to do that for one click but I don't know how to change the backgrounColors upon different clicks. I would like to implement some sort of an if statement that says that if the background of the current class==red than on click make the new current class yellow. In this example I can't get the background color to yellow and I really want to be yellow upon the third click of the div. in the future I like the 4th click create even another backgroundColor.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
     <head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <style type="text/css">
        .box{
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            background-color:green;
        }
        .red{
                width:200px;
            height:200px;
            background-color:red;
        }
        .yellow{
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
     </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.box').click(toRed)
        function toRed(e){
            $(this).addClass('red');
        }
        if($('this').hasClass('red')){
            $(this).removeClass('red')
            .addClass('yellow');
        }

            });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
   <div class="box"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

so in conclusion im basically trying  to change the backgroundcolor of the div when I click on it multiple times to different distinct colors each time. 
and why doesn't my code work.

Thank you for reading and thanks for your response in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FNMca/)**?

```
$('.box').click(toRed)
function toRed(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('red')) {
        $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('yellow');
    }
    $(this).addClass('red');
}​
```

Comment: Yes, this something like what I was looking for . Thank You

Comment: @JackSchuldenfrei - if you feel that this answers your question, please consider choosing it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic, simplest concept from what I gather your asking would be something like this:

```
$('.box').click(function()
{
    if($(this).hasClass('red'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('blue'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('blue').addClass('black');
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('black'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('black').addClass('white');
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('white'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('white').addClass('red');
    }
});
```

However let it be known there are methods you can use to make this even more elaborate, and more complex, and in doing so more intelligent. But I don't know how elaborate your need is, nor do I know if something more elaborate would be needed. It is definitely not thee most optimized way of handling it, but it should work all around none the less.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for multiple colors.  Just add more color classes to the array ([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mqF8P/)):

```
​$(function() {
    var colors = ["green","red","yellow"];

    $(".box").click(function(e) {
         var oldIndex = $.data(this, 'color-index') || 0, 
             newIndex = (oldIndex + 1 < colors.length ? oldIndex + 1 : 0);

        $(this).removeClass(colors[oldIndex]).addClass(colors[newIndex]);
        $.data(this, 'color-index', newIndex);
    });
});​
```